# Forza Horizon 3 crashes after clicking on "Ignore and continue"

Tags: technical-issues, forza-horizon-3

I downloaded and installed Forza Horizon 3 and after I launch the game a window says that my system is not good enough (how I expected it). But when I click on 'Ignore and continue' the game loads and then crashes. Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

#### Upgrade your PC, or if it can't be upgraded, buy a new one.

Unfortunately, that's your only option.

Your game is already telling you that your PC isn't good enough to run it. But since there's always a chance that the game might still run (albeit poorly), it gives you the option to ignore and continue. Unfortunately, the game wasn't kidding, and your PC *really* can't handle it.

---

What you can do to avoid this kind of situation in the future:

- Check the system requirements *before* you buy the game. It appears you already did that, which takes us to the following point:

  - **DO NOT** ignore those system requirements. They exist for a reason, as you've learned the hard way. In fact, be especially distrustful of RAM requirements. Those are usually written assuming there's nothing else on your system that uses RAM (there's *always* hundreds of applications or services that need RAM, even when running in the background).
- If checking the system requirements is too difficult, or you don't understand what they mean, or they change way too often: consider playing on a video game console instead, such as the Xbox One, the PS4, or the Nintendo Switch.

  - Note that console games have requirements as well, albeit much simpler ones. In 99% of the cases, it's which platform it'll run on. Even if a game can be played on different consoles, each copy of a game was built to run on a very specific console. A PS4 version of Call of Duty won't run on an Xbox One, and vice versa. You won't even get to see an "Ignore and Continue" if you try.

Comment: @ÁdámKara, the system requirements says you need at least 8 GB RAM. Even the Youtuber says his "Game crashes without warning." He's also playing the demo, which may or may not use less RAM than the main game. Also keep in mind that cracked games may introduce changes to the original code, which may or may not cause issues.

Comment: Just so you know, [you're not supposed to ask for support for pirated games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour): "Don't ask about... Questions about pirating games, or support for a game you've pirated"